# Why is my server telling me there is already an application running on port 3000?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, window, localhost, atom-editor

I am attempting to run a React application with a Rails backend. I have the rails server proxied to port 3001 and the React server set to run on 3000, and rake task set to start them both. However, when I run the rake command, the server starts, then shuts down immediately, saying that there is already something running on port 3000. I have checked using TCPview and confirmed that there is nothing running on port 3000, or for that matter, any port in the 3000's. Furthermore, I had a friend with a Mac clone the repo and attempt to start the server, and it worked fine for her. Any ideas as to what else could be causing this issue are greatly appreciated. For the record, I am on a windows machine, attempting to run the app in an atom terminal. Here is the package.json, specifying the proxy:

```
{
 "name": "fidirect",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
 "devDependencies": {
  "enzyme": "2.4.1",
  "react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.0",
  "react-scripts": "0.8.5"
},
```

Here is the procfile:

```
web: cd client && npm start
api: bundle exec rails s -p 3001
```

And here is the rake task:

```
task :start do
exec 'foreman start -p 3000'
end
```

Again, I know that this code works, I just cant figure out why it isnt working in my local environment, and there is definitely nothing running on port 3000. Thanks in advance for any and all help!
 Edit * Here is a full list of everything that comes up when I run netstat -po tcp. To my eye, this confirms nothing is running on the port. Am I missing something?

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    10.1.10.143:49435      msnbot-65-52-108-214:https  ESTABLISHED     
4004
TCP    10.1.10.143:49437      msnbot-65-52-108-235:https  ESTABLISHED     
4004
TCP    10.1.10.143:53182      msnbot-65-52-108-192:https  ESTABLISHED     
16656
TCP    10.1.10.143:53412      138.68.43.221:https    ESTABLISHED     17768
TCP    10.1.10.143:53556      pg-in-f188:5228        ESTABLISHED     7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53565      151.101.129.69:https   ESTABLISHED     7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53673      lb-192-30-253-125-iad:https  ESTABLISHED     
7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53715      a23-49-12-43:https     ESTABLISHED     7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53737      151.101.1.121:https    ESTABLISHED     7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53738      151.101.1.121:https    ESTABLISHED     7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53741      a104-91-221-98:https   ESTABLISHED     7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53746      151.101.1.121:https    ESTABLISHED     7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53749      151.101.1.121:https    ESTABLISHED     7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53754      151.101.2.202:https    ESTABLISHED     7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53759      a23-5-213-46:https     ESTABLISHED     7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53776      192.0.73.2:https       ESTABLISHED     7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53779      server-52-84-237-186:https  ESTABLISHED     
7504
TCP    10.1.10.143:53782      a-0001:https           ESTABLISHED     14932
TCP    10.1.10.143:53783      13.107.19.11:https     ESTABLISHED     14932
TCP    10.1.10.143:53784      13.107.6.254:https     ESTABLISHED     14932
TCP    10.1.10.143:53785      204.79.197.254:https   ESTABLISHED     14932
TCP    10.1.10.143:53786      13.107.42.254:https    ESTABLISHED     14932
TCP    10.1.10.143:53787      204.79.197.222:https   ESTABLISHED     14932
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes your server doesn't shutdown correctly.
In your terminal, run :

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

You'll see the running processes

```
ruby      91287 XXXXXX   10u  IPv4 032ce99031751a206c1      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

Then use the number displayed and kill it:

```
kill -9 91287
```

Repeat this operation until ruby processes are gone

Comment: I cannot use lsof. Is there a windows command that accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: if you open up the task manager you might be able to spot it there

Comment: "netstat -b" should display active ports on windows.